# Appending the "selected" option in select list via jquery [timezone selection list]

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I am trying to add "selected" option in select list of html when it matches user timezone,

Here is my try :- http://jsfiddle.net/HYfQ5/

I am not Javascript / jquery Student :'(

HTML List :-

```
<select name="timezone" id="timezone" required>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan" > Africa/Abidjan</option>
<option value="Africa/Accra" > Africa/Accra</option>
<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa" > Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>
....... <!--Rest Item is in Above Link, Don't want to fill this place with 480 items -->
</select>
```

and my Jquery modification :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/downloads/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tz = jstz.determine();
    var timez = new Array();
    var timez = $('#timezone').val();

    response_text = 'No timezone found';

    if (typeof (tz) === 'undefined') {
        response_text = 'No timezone found';
    }
    else {
        response_text = tz.name();
    }
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if (timez[i] === response_text) {
            $('#timezone').attr('selected') 
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

So, Whenever it matches the user timezone, it should automatically append "selected" value to select list.

Javascript timezone, i am using :- http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HYfQ5/2/

Calling val() on a **select** will select the option with that value, if any.

I have made following changes to the code:

```
var timez = $('#timezone');
```

and replaced the for loop by:

```
timez.val(response_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a little bug in your function. use this code:

```
$("#timezone option").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == response_text){
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    }
})
```

Instead of this:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if (timez[i] === response_text) {
        $('#timezone').attr('selected') 
    }
}
```

working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/HYfQ5/1/

Comment: Thanks bro, but i got some problem in my page with mine and your code. i followed http://jsfiddle.net/HYfQ5/2/ and is now working like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set .val() to a select list it will select the option with that value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var tz = jstz.determine();  
response_text = 'No timezone found';

if (typeof (tz) === 'undefined') {
    response_text = 'No timezone found';
}
else {
    response_text = tz.name();
}
$('#timezone').val(response_text);

});
```